# how to arrange items sequentially in row using flex-direction: row ;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

how do arrange these boxes sequentially in a row?
I tried to solve this problem using `flex-direction: row`; but it creates another problem  because each box have different hight

**HTML**

```css
#container {
  width: 35%;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

#container > div {
  width: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style='height: 10rem'>1</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>2</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>3</div>
  <div style='height: 9rem'>4</div>
  <div style='height: 3rem'>5</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>6</div>
  <div style='height: 2rem'>7</div>
  <div style='height: 7rem'>8</div>
  <div style='height: 9rem'>9</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>10</div>
  <div style='height: 7rem'>11</div>
  <div style='height: 1rem'>12</div>
  <div style='height: 11rem'>13</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>14</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>15</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#container > div {
    width: 5rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style='height: 10rem'>1</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>2</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>3</div>
  <div style='height: 9rem'>4</div>
  <div style='height: 3rem'>5</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>6</div>
  <div style='height: 2rem'>7</div>
  <div style='height: 7rem'>8</div>
  <div style='height: 9rem'>9</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>10</div>
  <div style='height: 7rem'>11</div>
  <div style='height: 1rem'>12</div>
  <div style='height: 11rem'>13</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>14</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>15</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, if you set only display: flex; (default value of flex-direction is row) and width: 100%;

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}
#container > div {
  width: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style='height: 10rem'>1</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>2</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>3</div>
  <div style='height: 9rem'>4</div>
  <div style='height: 3rem'>5</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>6</div>
  <div style='height: 2rem'>7</div>
  <div style='height: 7rem'>8</div>
  <div style='height: 9rem'>9</div>
  <div style='height: 5rem'>10</div>
  <div style='height: 7rem'>11</div>
  <div style='height: 1rem'>12</div>
  <div style='height: 11rem'>13</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>14</div>
  <div style='height: 6rem'>15</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "disolay" instead  "display" in containers > div.

Where did you used flex row ? In div or container?